# Spring websocket & binaryjs

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-boot, arrays

I use Spring 4.2.3 via spring-boot (1.3.0) at server and [binaryjs](http://binaryjs.com/) 0.2.1 at client.
Binaryjs successfully send data over websocket to server, but i can't receive it (bytes).
How to declare method, that will be receive `byte[]` from websocket (and save, e.g. into temporary file)?

Spring websocket config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/test");
    }
}
```

I do not use `withSockJS` because SockJS can't send bytearray data

```
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/test").withSockJS();
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, I have not found the solution